# Cast object (type double) to int

Tags: java, casting, int, double

Okay, so if I have this code

```
double a=1.5;
int b=(int)a;
System.out.println(b);
```

Everything works fine, but

```
Object a=1.5;
int b=(int)a;
System.out.println(b);
```

gives the following error after running (Eclipse doesn't give any error)

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Double cannot be cast to java.lang.Integer
```

Though, when I do

```
Object a=1.5;
double b=(double)a;
int c=(int)b;
System.out.println(c);
```

or

```
Object a=1.5;
int b=(int)(double)a;
System.out.println(b);
```

Nothing's wrong again.

Why do you have to cast it to `double` first ?

Comment: i am confused why your `Object a=1.5; double b=(double)a;` working it will work for the **java.lang.Double** class not for primitive **double**. In my eclipse that your working portion not working but this works:`double b=(Double)a;`

Comment: Well, start your own thread about that ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you declare the object `Object a = 1.5` you can tell by checking `System.out.println(a.getClass())` that the object is in fact cast to a `Double` instance. This can again be cast to a `double` because of unboxing conventions. After that the `double` value can be cast to an `int`.

There are however no unboxing conventions to cast from a Double instance to an `int`, so the runtime will issue an `ClassCastException` if you try and do that. It cannot directly go from `Double` to `Integer`.

Answer (score 3):

When you're casting from `Object`, you're [*unboxing*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.8) from the wrapper type... and you can only unbox to the original type, basically. It's effectively a cast to the relevant wrapper type, followed by a call to the appropriate `xxxValue` method. So this:

```
Object x = ...;
double d = (double) x;
```

is equivalent to:

```
Object x = ...;
double d = ((Double) x).doubleValue();
```

That cast to `Double` will obviously fail if `x` isn't a reference to a `Double`.

So your problematic code is equivalent to:

```
Object a = Double.valueOf(1.5); // Auto-boxing in the original code
int b = ((Integer) a).intValue(); // Unboxing in the original code
System.out.println(b);
```

Hopefully now it's obvious why that would fail - because the first line creates a `Double` which you're then trying to cast to `Integer`.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure why your code works at all. You should not be able to cast Object to 'double' because they are incompatible types. Also casting type int to double are incompatible types. Your first block of code:

```
double a=1.5;
int b=(int)a;
System.out.println(b);
```

will print "1". You will lose the decimals. If you want to just print the number before the decimal point then you can format your double when you print and you won't need to cast to type int.

But the reason the other don't work is because you are trying to cast to an incompatible type. It is strange that you say the last two blocks of code

```
Object a=1.5;
double b=(double)a;
int c=(int)b;
System.out.println(c);


Object a=1.5;
int b=(int)(double)a;
System.out.println(b);
```

These should not work because of incompatible types.

Comment: They should not work, and I know I _should_ use `Double.parseDouble(a.toString())`, but for some reason this works.

Comment: I'm not sure how you can get this to run, all but your first block of code will throw a java incompatible types error on compile. So it seems really odd that you can even run these.

Comment: I'm using Java 8 and I don't have any errors at all

Comment: How are you compiling your code - I am assuming you are using an IDE rather than on command line? I just tested each block in Java 7 & 8 in Intelij and it wont let me compile an other than the first block. E.g.

`public class Casting {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Object a=1.5;
        int b=(int)(double)a;
        System.out.println(b);
    }
}`

have you set up your IDE to ignore warnings?

Comment: I'm using Eclipse, full code here: http://pastebin.com/bRUVnuLA. Compiling via Terminal gives the following output: http://pastebin.com/aV8B5S3w

Comment: Thanks for the full example. I think there might be something wrong with your development environment. Eclipse should definitely be picking up these errors before you even compile your program. Maybe a good idea to check that you have Eclipse set up properly

Comment: Put "Boxing and unboxing conversions" to "Warning",  now I'm getting warnings like "The expression of type double is boxed into Double", thanks :)