# Why is Casting not transitive

Tags: java, c#, casting

Consider the following example in java (or c#):

```
 //doesn't work
 Object a = 5.2f;
 int b = (int)a; //java.lang.ClassCastException: java.base/java.lang.Float cannot be cast to java.base/java.lang.Integer

 //must first cast object to float, then can cast to integer
 Object a = 5.2f;
 int b = (int)(float)a;
```

I had always just assumed casting is transitive (`A=B & B=C THEN A=C`), however that obviously isn't the case.

Can someone explain exactly why this doesn't work?

Comment: In this case you do not only cast but also auto-box to a Float object.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24332413/java-auto-boxing-and-casting

Comment: Just in case you need to solve the specific problem, `int b = ((Number)a).intValue();` works for any numeric primitive type ([demo](https://ideone.com/L78ZvF))

Comment: @dasblinkenlight just asking out of curiosity, thanks though

Comment: Skeets answer here is what I was looking for: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27459780/cast-object-type-double-to-int/27459873#27459873